# Accidental expression evaluation in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, expression

Why this expression evaluating to 13 ?.

I accidentally evaluated this expression `(1_2).next` instead of `(1+2).next` which o/p 4 as result.

```
=> (1_2).next
=> 13
```

Please let me know how this is, as i m new to Ruby

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ruby allows you to use `_` to break up long numbers, for example

```
123456789 == 123_456_789
```

but the latter is a little easier to read, so your code is the same as `12.next`

Comment: what i was concern about that while following the tut for ruby, they explained that all things in ruby are objects so what i presume is even 1 and 2 are objects as well so how ruby concatenates it ??

Comment: @swapnesh Ruby's parser is ignoring the `_` and seeing only one object. Ruby is not concatenating two objects.

Comment: @oldergod was actually following the RoR so thought to cover some very basics of ruby though ..is it the right prth or I just go for the RoR ?

Comment: RoR is not a subset or superset of ruby but a collection of ruby libraries (gems). I would recommend understanding the basics of ruby to write simple but non trivial programs.

Answer (score 3):

1_2 is the same as 12. 12.next is 13. Underscores in numbers are ignored, you can use them for readability. E.g. 1000_000_000 is one billion.